# Cocoa app system restart

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Do you know any way to forcing restart an Mac OS computer from code? I tried an small applescript code without result. Applications ask for shutdown to the user so the user could stop the restarting procedure.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an usual thing to want to force. If the user is willing to type in their password and are an administrator of the computer; perhaps you can run

```
sudo reboot
```

from your application.

Comment: I finally did it allowing non root users to shutdown/reboot the system via: 'sudo chmod u+s /sbin/shutdown'. There are another ways but that was good enough for me.

Answer (score 3):

The official way is to send a system event to the login window process.  Apple's [Technical QA1134](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1134/_index.html) even includes a code example.

Answer (score 0):

Try using AppleScript/ScriptingBridge from your app to `tell application "Finder" to restart`.

Comment: AppleScript is awesome, "tell application "iTunes" to crash" :D